# How can I determine if an object or reference has a valid string coercion?

Tags: perl, reference, coercion

I've run into a situation (while logging various data changes) where I need to determine if a reference has a valid string coercion (e.g. can properly be printed into a log or stored in a database).  There isn't anything in [Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar::Util) to do this, so I have cobbled together something using other methods in that library:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw(reftype refaddr);

sub has_string_coercion
{
    my $value = shift;

    my $as_string = "$value";
    my $ref = ref $value;
    my $reftype = reftype $value;
    my $refaddr = sprintf "0x%x", refaddr $value;

    if ($ref eq $reftype)
    {
        # base-type references stringify as REF(0xADDR)
        return $as_string !~ /^${ref}\(${refaddr}\)$/;
    }
    else
    {
        # blessed objects stringify as REF=REFTYPE(0xADDR)
        return $as_string !~ /^${ref}=${reftype}\(${refaddr}\)$/;
    }
}

# Example:
use DateTime;
my $ref1 = DateTime->now;
my $ref2 = \'foo';

print "DateTime has coercion: " . has_string_coercion($ref1) . "\n\n";
print "scalar ref has coercion: " . has_string_coercion($ref2) . "\n";
```

However, I suspect there might be a better way of determining this by inspecting the guts of the variable in some way. How can this be done better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [perldoc overload](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html#Public-functions):

> `overload::StrVal(arg)`
>
> Gives string value of `arg`  as in absence of stringify overloading.

```
sub can_stringify {
    my ($obj) = @_;
    return "$obj" ne overload::StrVal($obj);
}
```

Note that `overload::Method` is not appropriate here [because](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html#%2a-_Boolean,-string-and-numeric-conversion_):

> 1. `'bool'`, `'""'`, `'0+'`,
>
> If one or two of these operations are not overloaded, the remaining ones can be used instead.

Therefore, checking only if `'""'` is overloaded would return false negatives compared to the method you show in your question.

Comment: I liked your earlier version better, that showed how to find the stringification method -- e.g. `perl -MDateTime -Moverload -wle'my $dt = DateTime->now; my $method = overload::Method($dt, q{""}); print $method->($dt)'`  :)

Comment: @Ether The problem is that `bool` might have been overloaded providing a stringification without `'""'` being overloaded.